# superagent post not passing through CGI args

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, cgi, superagent

Gday all, I'm replacing jQuery $.post() functions with superagent .post() calls.

They work fine calling CGI perl scripts without parms, but so far, I've been unable to pass CGI parms successfully.

e.g.

```
superagent
  .post('dir.cgi')
  .send({ dir: dir.path })
  .end(function(err, res){
  ...
```

By console logging, I've checked my args, and dir.path is valid. But when the perl CGI script runs, it says that dir is undefined?!

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance for any light on this matter!

Comment: Apparently, I need to turn this into a form, otherwise parms get passed as POSTDATA.

So I added 

.type('form')

with great hope, producing ... no change :(

Comment: Ok, after plalying around with argument passing, it now works.